# Splay tree visualization

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I must quickly create application which display splay tree, I would like to obtain something like in this applet http://techunix.technion.ac.il/~itai/ What is a good library for SWT which let me to do it ? I don't need a very good graphical features .. only simple binary tree in possible easy way.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of libraries to display and layout graphs in SWT.

Here is a small list:

- [JUNG (Java Universal Network/Graph Framework)](http://jung.sourceforge.net/index.html)
- [Zest: The Eclipse Visualization Toolkit](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/)
- [Draw2D](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/index.php)

Your question isn't very detailed, so just have a look and see which one suits your needs best.